# Clarification on proof that all groups of order $< 60$ are solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I've manged to prove that all groups of order $< 60$ are solvable, using Burnside's theorem. However, I found an alternate proof here [Question about solvable groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413056/question-about-solvable-groups/413612#413612) It states that:

"Note that $A_5$ is the smallest non-abelian simple group and its order is $60$. Therefore in any subnormal series of any group of order less than $60$, $A_5$ is not a composition factor. Hence all group of order less than $60$ are all solvable."

Could anyone explain why the fact that in any subnormal series of any group of order $< 60$, $A_5$ is not a composition factor implies that all groups of order less that $60$ are solvable? It's not clear to me why that follows immediately.

Comment: Well if $A_5$ is the smallest nonabelian simple group, then all composition factors of order less than $60$ must be abelian simple groups - i.e. they must be cyclic of prime order, so the group is solvable. But this is not really an alternative proof, because proving that $A_5$ is the smallest nonabelian simple group is essentially equivalent to proving that all groups oforder less than $60$ are solvable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N$ be a maximal normal subgroup. Then $G/N$ is simple and abelian (because it is smaller than $A_5$), hence cyclic. $N$ is strictly smaller than $G$, hence we may assume by induction that itis solvable, hence $G$ is solvable.