# Every group of order $440$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a group $G$ of order 440, it has a unique subgroup of order 11 which is normal in $G$. Let it be denoted $H$.

$H$ is clearly solvable, if $G/H$ was solvable, so it would be $G$. However I cannot seem to be able to show this last bit.
Any idea on how to show that $G/H$ is solvable? Also, any other idea on how to prove that $G$ is solvable would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $G/H$ is of order $40$, it is solvable - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985336/clarification-on-proof-that-all-groups-of-order-60-are-solvable).

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to prove that a group is solvable? What ways do you know?

Comment: @FareedAF Basically in my algebra course we have two basic methods so far, either you find a radical tower, or either you find an subgroup H, which is solvable and so that G/H is solvable

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much, that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G/H$ is a group of order $40$, so your same Sylow technique shows that it has a unique normal subgroup of order $5$, and once again reduces to a smaller case: now we can assume $|G|=8$. This is a $p$-group for $p=2$, therefore it is nilpotent and solvable.

Comment: If $H$ and $G/H$ are nilpotent, $G$ need not be nilpotent. in fact, not every group of order $440$ is nilpotent, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690316/for-which-numbers-n-is-every-group-of-order-n-nilpotent).

Comment: The dihedral group $D_{220}$ of order $440$ is not nilpotent, since $220$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: OK, but it still shows OP's group is solvable.

Comment: Yes, this is true.