# Show that $A_5$ is the only group which is not solvable with order less than 100

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

So I know that $A_5$ is not solvable but I don't know how to go about showing that other groups can't be solvable. I think that this theorem might be useful but I haven't found a smart way to use it. Thm: A group G is solvable iff $G^{(n)}=\{1\}$ for some n

Comment: I would think the Sylow theorems are helpful at least in excluding a lot of different possible orders. But I don't know a good general proof.

Comment: Do you know Burnside theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem?

Comment: Also look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413056/question-about-solvable-groups/413612#413612