# If $G$ has no subgroup with index $2$, how can I show that all subgroups with index $3$ are normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ has no subgroup with index $2$. How can I show that all subgroups with index $3$ are normal? (The index of the subgroup is the order of the quotient set.)

Comment: What thoughts do you have?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267593/on-group-containing-no-subgroup-of-index-2

Comment: I thought about the fact that there are only two costes and the subgroup covering the whole group. I tried to prove that the left cosets are equal to the right cosets unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of index $3$. Via the action of $G$ on the set $G/H$ of (left) cosets we get a group homomorphism $\alpha: G \rightarrow S_3$. Observe that $K = \ker \alpha$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

We claim that  $K = H$. Note that $\alpha(G)$ does not have a subgroup of index $2$ because $G$ doesn't. Also $\alpha(G) \neq 1$ because the action of $G$ on $G/H$ is nontrivial. So $\alpha(G)$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $S_3$ which has no index $2$ subgroup. This implies that $\alpha(G) \cong C_3$ (why?) so $|G:K| = |\alpha(G)| = 3$. Hence $K = H$.